# Radon-Nikodym derivative in a compact Hausdorff space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, c-star-algebras, radon-nikodym

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $m$ be a regular non-atomic probability measure defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$, and $g$ an autohomeomorphism of $X$. Suppose that the image measure $g_{\ast}m$ (defined by $g_{\ast}m(O) = m\big[g^{-1}(O)\big]$ for each Borel subset $O$) is equivalent to $m$. Then, for each $F\in C(X)$, I will have:

$$
\int_X F(x)\frac{d\,g_{\ast}m}{d\,m}(x)\,dm(x) = \int_X F(x)\,d(g_{\ast}m)(x) = \int_X F(x)\, dm(g^{-1}(x)) = \int_X F\circ g(x)\,dm(x)
$$

Define $\phi_m$ to be the positive linear functional defined by $m$ (and defined on $C(X)$) and $\phi_{g_{\ast}m}$ similarly, $I = \{F\in C(X): \phi_m(\vert\,f\,\vert)=0\}$ and $I_g = \{F\in C(X): \phi_{g_{\ast}m}(\vert\,f\,\vert) = 0\}$. Then the image of the following mapping:

$$
M: I_g\rightarrow I,\hspace{0.3cm} F(x) \mapsto F(x)\frac{d\,g_{\ast}m}{d\,m}(x)
$$
is equal to the image of the action (restrcited on $I_g$) defined by $g\bullet F(x) = F\circ g(x)$. Obviously both mappings are invertible and the action is a isometric isomorphism between $I_g$ and $I$. My questions are:

1. Since the action $F\mapsto g\bullet F$ is multiplicative, $M$ will never coincide with the action unless $g$ is the identity. In this case what can we tell about the local range of $(d\,g_{\ast}m/d\,m)$?
2. Is it true that, for each probability regular non-atomic measure $m$, there exists a non-identity element $g\in\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ (the homeomorphism group of $X$) such that $m$ is equivalent to $g_{\ast}m$?
3. Given a non-trivial subgroup $G\subseteq\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$, will there exist a regular non-atomic probability measure $m$ such that $g_{\ast}m\sim m$ for each $g\in G$?

**Update**: Let $m$ be a probability regular non-atomic measure and assume $g\in\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ satisfies $m\sim gm$. According to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417723), we can find a compact set $C_{\epsilon}$ such that both $m(C_{\epsilon})$ and $gm(C_{\epsilon})$ are less than $\epsilon$. I tried to use this and the **Urysohn's Lemma** to decide the local behavior of the derivative but failed. Any hints will be appreciated.

**Update2**: From the **Corollary 6.2.2** in **Measures on topological space** written by *V.I.Bogachev* ([link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf02432851)), for a fixed $g\in\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$, one can find a Radon probability measure $m$ (and hence regular when $X$ is compact) such that $g_{\ast}m = m$. In such case, compared to my original question, I suppose it would not be too greedy to ask, given $m$ a probability measure, is it possible to find a subgroup $G\subseteq\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ such that $g_{\ast}m\sim m$ for each $g\in G$.

Comment: A standard notation for what you call “$gm$” is $g_\ast m$ or $g_\sharp m$, the ‘pushforward’ notation. By ‘equivalent’ do you mean: $gm\ll m$, that $gm$ is absolutely continuous wrt $m$?

Comment: What do you want, when you say ‘find the local behaviour’? Is there a specific motivation, do you want a bound on the size of the function, do you want to show it is continuous, …?

Comment: By "$m$ equivalent to $g_{\ast}m$", I mean $m\gg g_{\ast}m$ and $g_{\ast}m\gg m$. Also, sorry for the typo and I mean to know the local range of the derivative. As $\epsilon$ becomes arbitrarily small, I can still find an $F\in C(X)$ such that the support of $F$ is $C_{\epsilon}$ and also $F$ obtains its maximum, say $1$, in $C_{\epsilon}$. Therefore, I suppose multiplying $F$ by the derivative would not make the essential sup of the product too far away from $1$, and hence by regularity, can find an open set where the range of the derivative is near $1$.

Comment: This question is also posted in MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446735