# A Question Over set partitioning

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, set-theory, set-partition

There is a bit in the proof, the link, I couldn't understand.
"There exists a sequence $(Π)$ of partitions, such that for each $$,$Π$ is an $+1/$-partition" How are we sure that there is a $+1/$-partition of the set $A$ for all $n$?
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/641727/1112387